# How do I model teams, games, and home/away team relationships within Core Data?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I am trying to use Core Data to represent a sports league's schedule. Within my model I have an entity called Team and an entity called Game. Each team will have many games. Each game will have two teams, one that is identified as the home team and the other that is identified as the away team.

In my current approach I have defined "homeTeam" and "awayTeam" relationships within the Game entity. Each of those relationships are to-one and have their destinations set to the Team entity. I have also defined a to-many "games" relationship within the Team entity that has its destination set to the Game entity.

The problem with this approach is that I can't set the inverse relationships in any appropriate way. It would require the Team/games relationship to be the inverse of both the Game/homeTeam and the Game/awayTeam relationships, and that isn't allowed (as far as I can tell). I could of course define these as unidirectional relationships but I start getting Xcode warnings and I'm not sure that's a good thing to do here.

I've also considered removing the awayTeam and the homeTeam relationships from the Game entity and replacing it with a teams relationship. That relationship would be many-to-many with Team, with a min and max value of 2. However, the approach doesn't allow me to distinguish between the home team and the away team, which I will need to do in my app.

I'd appreciate any recommendations for the best way to represent these kind of relationships within CoreData. I could no doubt implement this myself using my own DB layer, but I'd rather rely on CoreData than come up with a home-grown solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

`Game` has two one-to-one relationships, `homeTeam` and `guestTeam`.

`Team` has two one-to-many-relationships, `homeGames` and `outGames`. The inverse of `homeGames` is `homeTeam`, and the inverse of `outGames` is `guestTeam`.

Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks Mundi - I hadn't thought of that and it does make some sense. I have one question with this approach: Is there a straightforward way to fetch an ordered list of all games for a team? When I had a single "games" relationship for the Team entity I was planning to implement a fetch request that returned all games ordered by date. I'm not sure how easy that would be with all games now spanning a collection or home games and a separate collection of away games.

Comment: Easiest is to fetch all homeGames and outGames as objects of type Game and then sort the array using the date property programmatically. With a few dozens records or less this should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that. I'm also experimenting with a fetch request that returns all games that matches "Any" of two expressions. The first expression looks for a home team that matches a team specified as a parameter and the second expression looks for an away team that matches.